# SQL Query on Date function to fetch rows in history dynamically

Tags: sql-server, rdbms

Team,
I am looking for a date function that when i use it in procedures, it should automatically get the desired range looking at parameter.
ex: query should show me results from today's date to 90 days in history.
like

```
select * from Table
where dataFunction(currDate, 90)
```

where currDate should consider todays date and pull me all the rows for past 90 days.

am using MSSMS v17.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't write functions for this. They don't play well with indexes, which cuts to the core of database performance. You need to use the built-in items in the WHERE clause... something more like this:

```
select * 
from Table
where Table.DateColumn BETWEEN DATEADD(d, -90, current_timestamp) AND current_timestamp
```

If you really want to use just the date, instead of the full DateTime value, then cast as date:

```
select * 
from Table
where Table.DateColumn BETWEEN DATEADD(d, -90, cast(current_timestamp as date)) AND cast(current_timestamp as date)
```

Comment: Using between on dates is usually not recommended, but if you decide to do so its good to add a buffer to the max.

Answer (score 0):

You seek the DATEADD() function.

Comment: yes i see that but am still not clear. it just returns the date but how to use in query so I get all rows from that returned date to today? 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp

Comment: WHERE MyColumn >= DATEADD(d, -90, GETDATE())

Answer (score 0):

The [`DATEADD()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) function gives you what you need.

Replace `<DATE_FROM_TABLE>` with the field you're comparing:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE <DATE_FROM_TABLE> >= DATEADD(DAY, -90, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the query you are searching for:

```
Select   *
from     Table t
where    t.date >= dateadd(day, -90, getdate())
```